# Ordering columns in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, sql-query-store

I have data in DB

---

Germany
India
USA
China
Japan
Africa

---

I want a sql query which results:

---

India (India as first row)
Africa   (all the other alphabetically arranged)
Japan
USA
China (China as last row)

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use several levels of sorting:

```
order by col = 'India' desc, col = 'China', col
```

Rationale: in MySQL, expression `col = <val>` returns `1` if the condition is fulfilled, else `0`.  So `col = 'India' desc` puts India first, while `col = 'China'` puts China last. Ties are then broken with a regular sort on the country name.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, you can do:

```
order by (col = 'India') desc,
         (col = 'China') asc,
         col asc
```

Or use a `case` expression:

```
order by (case when col = 'India' then 1
               when col = 'China' then 3
               else 2
          end)
         col
```